# I cant write the correct SQL query correcty

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, qsqlquery

I have 2 table in the database and ı am trying to filter some users according to some criterias.

```
criterias table

+---------+----------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| user_id | searching_friendship | searching_practice | conversation_subject |
+---------+----------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 31      |                      |                    | science              |
| 26      |  on                  | on                 | love                 |
| 32      |  on                  | off                | science              |
| 34      |                      |                    |                      |
+---------+----------------------+--------------------+----------------------+


user table
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
| user_id | user_name  | user_email                  | user_password | user_gender | user_language | language_lvl | last_login       |
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
| 26      | Furkan     | furkanakgun@windowslive.com | 123           |             | TÃ¼rkiye      | basic        | 16.06.2019 11:57 |
| 31      | sfsdf      | asdfasdf@hotmail.com        | 123           | Male        | Afrikaans     | basic        | 09.06.2019 20:01 |
| 32      | denemeuser | xxx@hotmail.com             | 123           | Male        | Amharic       | intermediate | 16.06.2019 11:57 |
| 33      | Smith      | ssdf                        | 123           | male        | ing           | upper        | NULL             |
| 34      | luser      | llll@hotmai.com             | 123456        | Male        | Afrikaans     | basic        | 16.06.2019 10:32 |
+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
```

I am trying to match users who have same criterias.What i do is

```
$userId=$_SESSION['userId'];
$sql="SELECT* FROM criterias WHERE user_id='$userId'";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $friendshipCheck=$result['searching_friendship'];
    $pracCheck=$result['searching_practice'];
    $conversationSub=$result['conversation_subject'];
}
```

so I am getting current criterias informations and ı am trying to match with other users like this

```
SELECT* FROM users,criterias WHERE (users.user_id=criterias.user_id AND users.user_id!='$userId') AND criterias.searching_friendship='$friendshipCheck' OR criterias.searching_practice='$pracCheck'
```

But it doesnt work. Do you have any idea how to fix this dear friends ?

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide details about the expected result and your actual result from the query.

Comment: For example I am a user and want to chat someone who is online the website.Then ı choose some filters like conversation subject. Lets say ı choose Love and other 2 people choosed love . so ı have to see only who choosed same criteria as i did

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Explain "it doesn't work". Which one--mysql or postgresql? Show the actual text you are executing in SQL. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & base table initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get only the users with the same criteria as yours this query should work

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN criterias AS c ON u.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE u.user_id != '$userId'
  AND c.searching_friendship = '$friendshipCheck'
  AND c.searching_practice = '$pracCheck'
  AND c.conversation_subject = '$conversation_subject'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it really helped me alot. :)

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark the answer as correct if it works for you as it should.

Comment: Just curious, why you are fetching all the attributes of the given userid in one query and then writing a separate query where you are feeding those inputs, when all of that can be accomplished in a single query?

Comment: It is only one query, where for every user I make join with criterias table to get the criterias for every user, and then only filtering the result set of the join operation to get the users that have SAME criteria as that with id = `$userId`. And I return all attributes because I don't know what specific attributes (columns) he need, it's up to him to choose. And yes, it can be accomplished in one query but he already started on this way and I just made the query to work. Maybe he has his own purposes why he go on that way.

Comment: @Stefcho, sorry my question was actually directed towards Furkan . I should have been clear n that part. Yes, I saw what you are doing. That looks good in terms of Furkan's 2 query approach.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the expected results vs what you are getting would help proving the best solution.
Here, I am trying to write the query based on the understanding of what you have tried to write in your code:

```
;WITH  CTE AS
    (
           SELECT  C.*
           FROM    Criterias C
           WHERE   C.user_id = <user_id_input>
    )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    User U
            INNER JOIN Criterias C
                ON U.user_id = C.user_id
    WHERE   EXISTS ( 
                       SELECT 1
                       FROM   CTE 
                       WHERE  CTE.searching_friendship = C.searching_friendship
                       OR     CTE.searching_practice   = C.searching_practice
                   )
     AND        U.user_id != <input_user_id> ;
```